# XMLNamespace prefix is not defined on row

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, soap

I need to generate the exact following two lines that are part of a XML file, which I managed to generate and works perfectly.

```
<q17:DestinationGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
<q17:DestinationCoord xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

I have been trying all methods related to the XML namespaces but I really don't know what to do else. If I won't be able to achieve this, I need to start learing `Java` in order to generate the XML.

**This is the rest of my code, so far:**

```
    DECLARE @RootNode NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SOAPHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SOAPBody NVARCHAR (MAX)
    DECLARE @XMLProductsLines NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @XMLSalesOrders NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @XMLSalesOrders2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @XMLHQ NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @XMLFinal NVARCHAR(MAX)



    SET @SOAPHeader='<s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
    +'<To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://10.2.3.92:8201/FlexibleStorage/Transmission?wsdl</To>'
    +'<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Interfaces/TransmissionServer/StoreDocument</Action>'
    +'</s:Header>'

    SET @XMLProductsLines=''

    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects' as q17)

    SELECT @XMLProductsLines=(SELECT ProductCode 'q17:ProductCode', OrderedQuantity 'q17:OrderedQuantity'
    FROM PurchasesDocumentsLines 
    FOR XML RAW ('q17:OrderedProductSection'), ROOT('q17:OrderedProducts'), ELEMENTS)

    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects' as q17)

    SELECT @XMLSalesOrders=(SELECT DestCode 'q17:DestinationCode', DestDescr 'q17:DestinationName'
    FROM PurchaseDocumentsHeader
    FOR XML RAW ('q17:DestinationSection'), ROOT('q17:DestinationSection'), ELEMENTS)

    SET @SOAPBody=
    '<soapenv:Body>'
    +'<tns:StoreDocument xmlns:tns="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Interfaces">'
    +'<tns:StoreDocumentMessage>'
    +'<q1:SystemCode xmlns:q1="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Messages">ROM_ENTSOFT_PROD</q1:SystemCode>' -- system code
    +'<q1:TransmissionUID xmlns:q1="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Messages">'+convert(nvarchar(36), newid())+'</q1:TransmissionUID>' -- generated GID
    +'<q1:DocumentSection xmlns:q1="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Messages">' 
    +'<q17:DocumentType xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">1</q17:DocumentType>' -- fix value (1) 
    +'<q17:DocumentNumber xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">0000006965</q17:DocumentNumber>' -- ADCode of delivery note
    +'<q17:DocumentUID xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- not used
    +'<q17:CreationDateTimeUTC xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'+format((SELECT esdcreated FROM PurchaseDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')+'</q17:CreationDateTimeUTC>' -- timestamp of the order
    +'<q17:DocumentStatus xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">2</q17:DocumentStatus>' -- 1 = Open; 2 = Shipped;
    +'<q17:LatestGoodIssueDate xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'+format(getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')+'</q17:LatestGoodIssueDate>' -- the date when the goods are shipped
    +'<q17:Reference xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">0000013254</q17:Reference>' -- invoice number
    +'<q17:TotalOrderedProducts xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- not used
    +@XMLProductsLines
    +'<q17:RelatedDocumentSection xsi:nil="true" xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- left empty (not used)
    +'<q17:StockOwnerSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'
    +'<q17:StockOwnerCode>ITDR</q17:StockOwnerCode>'
    +'<q17:StockOwnerName>Imperial Tobacco Romania Distribution</q17:StockOwnerName>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerAddress1>140-160 Nicolae Canea Street, EOS Business Park, 1st Floor, 2nd District, Bucharest, ROMANIA</q17:StockOwnerAddress1>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerAddress2/>'
    +'<q17:StockOwnerZIP>023076</q17:StockOwnerZIP>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerCity>BUCHAREST</q17:StockOwnerCity>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerNameRomanized>Imperial Tobacco Romania Distribution</q17:StockOwnerNameRomanized>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerAddress1Romanized>140-160 Nicolae Canea Street, EOS Business Park, 1st Floor, 2nd District, Bucharest, ROMANIA</q17:StockOwnerAddress1Romanized>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerAddress2Romanized/>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerZIPRomanized>023076</q17:StockOwnerZIPRomanized>' 
    +'<q17:StockOwnerCityRomanized>BUCHAREST</q17:StockOwnerCityRomanized>'
    +'<q17:StockOwnerCountry>RO</q17:StockOwnerCountry>'
    +'<q17:StockOwnerGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>' -- left empty (not used)
    +'</q17:StockOwnerSection>'
    +@XMLSalesOrders
    -- here I need the two lines
    --+'<q17:DestinationGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    --+'<q17:DestinationCoord xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    +'<q17:SoldToSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">' -- the headquarter for each POS above
    +'<q17:SoldToCode>13400001</q17:SoldToCode>'
    +'<q17:SoldToName>Табако Трейд ООД</q17:SoldToName>'
    +'<q17:SoldToAddress1>Пловдив бул. Христо Ботев 94</q17:SoldToAddress1>'
    +'<q17:SoldToAddress2 xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    +'<q17:SoldToZIP>4000</q17:SoldToZIP>'
    +'<q17:SoldToCity>Пловдив</q17:SoldToCity>'
    +'<q17:SoldToNameRomanized>Tobacco Trade LTD</q17:SoldToNameRomanized>'
    +'<q17:SoldToAddress1Romanized>137 Bresovsko shose Str.</q17:SoldToAddress1Romanized>'
    +'<q17:SoldToAddress2Romanized xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    +'<q17:SoldToZIPRomanized>4000</q17:SoldToZIPRomanized>'
    +'<q17:SoldToCityRomanized>Plovdiv</q17:SoldToCityRomanized>'
    +'<q17:SoldToCountry>BG</q17:SoldToCountry>'
    +'<q17:SoldToGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    +'<q17:SoldToSameGroupAsStockOwner>false</q17:SoldToSameGroupAsStockOwner>'
    +'</q17:SoldToSection>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationSection xmlns:q17="http://ITrack.Transmission/2011/02/25/Objects">'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationCode>Burda</q17:TrackingLocationCode>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationName>Импириъл Табако Дистрибуция ЕООД</q17:TrackingLocationName>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress1>Tarlaua 41/1, CF 55639, Dragomiresti Vale, Numar cadastral 55639</q17:TrackingLocationAddress1>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress2></q17:TrackingLocationAddress2>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationZIP></q17:TrackingLocationZIP>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationCity>Dragomiresti Vale</q17:TrackingLocationCity>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationNameRomanized>Burda</q17:TrackingLocationNameRomanized>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress1Romanized>Tarlaua 41/1, CF 55639, Dragomiresti Vale, Numar cadastral 55639</q17:TrackingLocationAddress1Romanized>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationAddress2Romanized></q17:TrackingLocationAddress2Romanized>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationZIPRomanized></q17:TrackingLocationZIPRomanized>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationCityRomanized>Dragomiresti Vale</q17:TrackingLocationCityRomanized>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationCountry>RO</q17:TrackingLocationCountry>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationGLN xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    +'<q17:TrackingLocationCoord xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'
    +'</q17:TrackingLocationSection>'
    +'</q1:DocumentSection>'
    +'</tns:StoreDocumentMessage>'
    +'</tns:StoreDocument>'
    +'</soapenv:Body>'




    SET @RootNode='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+@SOAPHeader+@SOAPBody+'</soapenv:Envelope>'

    DECLARE @XMLFileDescription varchar(250);
    SET @XMLFileDescription='StoreDocument'+'.xml

EXEC ExportXML @RootNode,'D:\TT', @XMLFileDescription'
```

And I get the error below, but I really don't know where to define the namespace or at least my mind does not think more "out of the box".

> Namespace prefix q17 on DestinationGLN is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Right besides the devil of spaghetti code whispering in your right ear about `CURSOR`s and procedural thinking (see you other questions :-D) there is the devil of wrong tools, whispering in your left ear about creating XML via string concatenation. There are several reasons why you **never should do that!**.

If one of your concatenated values would include a forbidden character (namely `&, < and >`) this will break! This might pass all internal tests and break in the customer's system. Very bad...

And behind you there is the devil of wrong types, whispering to you about russian characters in `VARCHAR`.

Try

```
SELECT 'Табако Трейд ООД',
      N'Табако Трейд ООД';
```

the result

```
varchar             nvarchar
?????? ????? ???    Табако Трейд ООД
```

See what I mean? Always use `NVARCHAR`!

### about your error

It is not allowed to treat a string as XML (even if it looks like valid XML!) if there is a namespace prefix, which is not declared.

Comment: Understood. Can you guide me in such way on how to achieve this? How or where to declare those namespaces in my case? Thanks

Comment: @cdrrrrr, Did you read my other answers to your previous questions?

Comment: I am about to do now. Come back with a feedback. Thanks